# How do I display errors in a form without repating code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Ok, for example I have a field like this:

`<textarea id="feedbackBody" name="feedbackBody" class="fullwidth"></textarea>` and I thought I should be able to do something like this in my logic code:

*IF ERROR*

```
<textarea id="inputWarning" name="feedbackBody" class="fullwidth"></textarea>
<span class="help-inline">Eroor</span>
```

So my server, could just show the span below the field IF error=yes in the url, and then I could change the ID of textarea and make the help-line visible.

However, this doesn't work, it doesn't show the error styling.

The documentation shows that to show an error I'd have to do something like this:

```
<div class="control-group warning">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Input with warning</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <textarea id="inputwarning" name="feedbackBody" class="fullwidth"></textarea>
                  <span class="help-inline">Something may have gone wrong</span>
                </div>
              </div>
```

That's an awful lot of code to warp around all the fields just to show an error...there has to be a better way. Because the way it looks like right now I'd have to on page have code like this:

IF NO ERROR

```
<textarea id="feedbackBody" name="feedbackBody" class="fullwidth"></textarea>
```

ELSE

```
<div class="control-group warning">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning">Input with warning</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <textarea id="inputwarning" name="feedbackBody" class="fullwidth"></textarea>
                      <span class="help-inline">Something may have gone wrong</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

So I can't just "show" a simple span below, but have to recreate the whole field with all that stuff around it.

Comment: @Damian0o do you care to elaborate?

Comment: From where validation come from. What server site technology are you using? You did not write anything at all...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are programming in ASP.NET MVC, which might not be the case (you should tag your question with the language used).

This is not a direct solution to your problem, but it may help you. Try out a library discussed on [this video: TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LpWMl5D2i4).